# IIS 7 Wont Open My Aspx Files

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am new to IIS and it is annoying the hell out of me!

I have an asp.NET website that runs beautifully on visual studio 2010, so what i do, is publish the website, put the published website folder in the inetpub/wwwroot folder, connect all the dots, then in my browser i type in `http://localhost:8080/A3Media/` and it brings up my index.html page. So the IIS is working correctly because it happily displays .html files. but when i try and access a .aspx file in my website. I get i weird 404 error saying the document doesnt exist. When it obviously does exist because... I checked... multiple times!

So i deducted that my IIS doesnt like .aspx files or anything to do with asp.NET.

So i make sure that i have all the asp.net modules installed by following the usual "windows features" and making sure the asp.net folder is ticked and installed, along with all the depending asp.net folders.

and my website still doesnt work.

have i missed something?

i have no idea:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of two options spring to mind.

1. Have you registered ASP.NET? `aspnet_regiis.exe -i` [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

   cmd -> cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319> aspnet_regiis.exe -i
2. In IIS manager - Request Filtering - Is .aspx denied?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you convert your "A3Media" directory into ASP.NET Application via IIS Manager, please see [Deploying ASP.NET Websites on IIS 7.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/IIS7ASPNet.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Shortcut to the section on the page that is interesting in this case: [How to Deploy ASP. Net Websites on IIS 7.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/IIS7ASPNet.aspx#DeployonIIS7)